# Titanium design advice

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, commonjs

While learning Appcelerator Titanium, I'm building an app that starts with a Window that contains 2 labels. The two labels (onclick) should open 2 different Windows (each containing tabgroups).

So, in my `app.js` I have:

```
Window = require('ui/handheld/ApplicationWindow');
```

and in my `ApplicationWindow` function:

```
    var window1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor:'#ffffff'
    });

    var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({ text: "Open first Window", top:10 });
    window1.add(label);

    var label2 = Ti.UI.createLabel({ text: "Open second Window", top:50 });
    window1.add(label2);

    var window2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({url:"A.js",backgroundColor:'#00ff00'});
    var window3 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({url:"B.js",backgroundColor:'#ff0000'});

    label.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var t = Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.CURL_UP;
    window1.animate({view:window2,transition:t},function(){window2.open();});
    });

    label2.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var t = Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.CURL_UP;
    window1.animate({view:window3,transition:t},function(){window3.open();});
    }); 

    return window1;
```

The first question is: is this a good design? Is it improvable? How?

The second question is: is there a way to show the page I'm opening before the end of the transition? At the moment it seems the JS contained in A.js and B.js is executed only when the animation stops.

Thanks, any help is welcome and sorry for the newbie question.

[EDIT] This is my current code after Ch4rAss's comment:

```
function ApplicationWindow() {

    var root = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor:'#ffffff'
    });

    var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({ text: "Open first Window", top:10 });
    root.add(label);

    var label2 = Ti.UI.createLabel({ text: "Open second Window", top:50 });
    root.add(label2);

    var win2 = require('ui/handheld/Win2');
    var win3 = require('ui/handheld/Win3');

    label.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var t = Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.CURL_UP;
    win2.open({transition:t});
    });

   label2.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   var t = Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.CURL_UP;
    win3.open({transition:t});
   }); 

    return root;
}

module.exports = ApplicationWindow;
```

and:

```
function Win2(){
        /* You can (of course) do more than this */
        return Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor:'#00ff00'});
    }
module.exports = Win2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add animation to `open()` method in order to open window during an animation:

```
window1.open({transition:Titanium.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.CURL_UP});
```

I would recommend to use separate file for each window and use CommonJS to `require()` it. Same approach as you use for `ApplicationWindow`. In moment you creating two windows and loading them to memory without using them! Better would be:

```
var Win1 = require('ui/handheld/WhateverWindow');
label.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   var win1 = new Win1();
   win1.open({transition:Titanium.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.CURL_UP});
});
```

And `ui/handheld/WhateverWindow.js`

```
(function() {
    var WhateverWindow = function() {
        /* You can (of course) do more than this */
        return Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor:'#00ff00'});
    }
    module exports = WhateverWindow;
})();
```

You can read more [here](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium).

Comment: This is not working for me. I changed a little your code and the function W2 in W2.js file became: `function Win2(){return Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor:'#00ff00'});}module.exports = Win2;` . The calling code is very similar to yours but I receive an error when I click. My code: `var win2 =require('ui/handheld/W2');label.addEventListener("click", function(e) {var t = Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.CURL_UP;win2.open({transition:t});});` The error:  line = 30;
  message = "'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'win2.open({transition:t})')";
    name = TypeError;
    sourceId = 208669216;

Comment: Maybe I undestand, but I wait for our comment: I must instantiate the win this way: var Win2 = require('ui/handheld/Win2'); var win2 = new Win2(). Then, win.open(...)...

Comment: Sry, I've accidentally forget to create a window object. See my edit.

Comment: Ok, one more question: if I want to close the opened window I noticed I can use close and pass a transition (like open). I tested it and it worked but I saw the root window content only appears after the end of the transition. Is it possible to change this?